# Case sensitive search query with IN clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, collate

I want to do a case sensitive search in SQL Server environment. Whenever I am using separate queries like below, it is working fine:

```
select * from table1 where flag = 'Yes' COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as;
select * from table1 where flag = 'No' COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as;
```

But how to achieve this functionality when I am using a IN clause like below:

```
select * from table1 where flag in ('Yes', 'No'); //This is returning all the flag vlaues like Yes, YES, NO, No
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you did your 2 examples, use `COLLATE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE flag COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as IN ('Yes', 'No');
```

Comment: The COLLATE clause can prevent indexes from being used so one can add `AND flag IN ('Yes', 'No')` so that the insensitive search may be done via an index seek and the case-sensitive predicate used to further filter the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Set the column collation properly, and you're done - for ever!

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN flag varchar(3) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
```

Now you can simply do:

```
select * from table1 where flag = 'Yes';
select * from table1 where flag in ('Yes', 'No');
```